# How to join same table to get parent ID data in Sequelize-Typescript?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I'm using Sequelize with the Sequelize-Typecript decorators, and I want to join data from the same table but getting the data from a parent ID.

This a test model called "Element"

```
@Table({
    timestamps:false,
    tableName: "element"
});

export class Element extends Model {

    @Column({
        type: DataType.INTEGER,
        primaryKey:true,
        allowNull:false,
        autoIncrement:true
    })
    id!:number;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.STRING,
        allowNull:false,
    })
    name!:string;

    @ForeignKey(() => Element)
    @Column({
        type: DataType.INTEGER,
        allowNull:false,
    })
    parent_id!:number;

    @BelongsTo(() => Element)
    parent_element!: Element;
}
```

By using Element.findAll(), I want to get this example result (as a JSON):

```
"element": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Car",
            "parent_id": null,
            "parent_element": {}
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Engine",
            "parent_id": 1,
            "parent_element": {
                 "id": 1,
                 "name": "Car"
                 "parent_id": null
            }
        }
]
```

But instead, "parent_element" data gets ignored, like that:

```
"element": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Car",
            "parent_id": null
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Engine",
            "parent_id": 1
            }
        }
]
```

So, I wonder how to get the data of the parent_id from the same table. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the element again inside your findAll call. It will return the data of the parent element.

```
const data = await Element.findAll({
     include:[{model:Element}],
   });
```